# Conditional formatting(cell highlighting) of pandas DataFrame columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-formatting

I have made a script for daily trending of data & for the same I want to highlight cells value by color if it has deviated from the previous day value. Column headers will vary based on the date. Hence I am using a column index to locate it.

I am new to conditional formatting and do not have much depth idea.
My effort is below, but I am getting errors.
My dataframe looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PtlP.png)

code :

```
import pandas as pd

def highlight_greater(x):
    r = 'red'
    g = 'gray'

    m1 = df1[df1.columns[(-2)]] > df1[df1.columns[(-4)]]
    m2 = df1[df1.columns[(-2)]] < df1[df1.columns[(-4)]]

    df1 = pd.DataFrame('background-color: ', index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)

    df1[df1.columns[(-2)]] = np.where(m1, 'background-color: {}'.format(r), df1[df1.columns[(-2)]])
    df1[df1.columns[(-2)]] = np.where(m2, 'background-color: {}'.format(g), df1[df1.columns[(-2)]])
    return df1


dfstyled = dfnew.style.apply(highlight_greater,subset[dfnew[dfnew.columns[-2]]],axis=1)

dfstyled.to_excel("C:\\Users\\mine\\styled.xlsx",engine='openpyxl')
```

desired Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG0oF.png)